# How to loop through a list of dictionary and extract those with the same 'name' and 'school' into a new list while getting their other values in it

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have this list of dictionary and I would like to get those with the same exact value of 'name' and 'school' into a new list and also getting their 'age' merged into a list as well and the rest of the dictionary that is not identical to just add into the list as per usual..

Here is an example of the list of dictionary

```
[{'name': 'Jane', 'age':12, 'school': 'SIT'}, {'name': 'John', 'age':13, 'school': 'SMU'},{'name': 'Jane', 'age':14, 'school': 'SIT'}, {'name': 'Jane', 'age':16, 'school': 'SIT'}, {'name': 'John', 'age':13, 'school': 'NUS'}]
```

and I would like it to make it into something like this..

```
[{'name': 'Jane', 'age': [12,14,16], 'school': 'SIT'}, {'name': 'John', 'age': 13, 'school': 'SMU'}, {'name': 'John', 'age':13, 'school': 'NUS'}]
```

using Python.. please help!

tried using counter, loops but still can't get it to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `itertools.groupby()`.

Example:

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

data = [{'name': 'Jane', 'age':12, 'school': 'SIT'}, {'name': 'John', 'age':13, 'school': 'SMU'},{'name': 'Jane', 'age':14, 'school': 'SIT'}, {'name': 'Jane', 'age':16, 'school': 'SIT'}, {'name': 'John', 'age':13, 'school': 'NUS'}]

keyfunc = lambda x: (x["name"], x["school"])
# needs to be sorted to use groupby
data.sort(key=keyfunc)
output = []
for k,v in itertools.groupby(data, key=keyfunc):
    this_group = {
        "name": k[0],
        "school": k[1],
        "age": [i["age"] for i in v],
    }
    output.append(this_group)

pprint(output)
```

The output is:

```
[{'age': [12, 14, 16], 'name': 'Jane', 'school': 'SIT'},
 {'age': [13], 'name': 'John', 'school': 'NUS'},
 {'age': [13], 'name': 'John', 'school': 'SMU'}]
```

---

If you wish to go with the solution based on a buffer dictionary, please check out the `dict.setdefault()` method.

Example:

```
buffer = {}
for i in data:
    buffer.setdefault((i["name"], i["school"]), []).append(i["age"])
```

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault

Answer (score 0):

```
x =  [{'name': 'Jane', 'age':12, 'school': 'SIT'}, {'name': 'John', 'age':13, 'school': 'SMU'},{'name': 'Jane', 'age':14, 'school': 'SIT'}, {'name': 'Jane', 'age':16, 'school': 'SIT'}, {'name': 'John', 'age':13, 'school': 'NUS'}]

new_x = {}
for r in x:
    if r['name'] in new_x.keys():
        if not isinstance(new_x[r['name']]['age'], list):
            new_x[r['name']]['age'] = [new_x[r['name']]['age']]
        if r['age'] not in new_x[r['name']]['age']:
            new_x[r['name']]['age'].append(r['age'])
    else:
        new_x[r['name']] = {'age': r['age'], 'school': r['school']}
z = [v.update(name=k) for k, v in new_x.items()]
z = [v for k, v in new_x.items()]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a universal solution to your problem. Only `name` and `school` are considered "special". All other keys, like `age` are converted to list when a new value has to be added.

```
l = [
    {"name": "Jane", "age": 12, "school": "SIT"},
    {"name": "John", "age": 13, "school": "SMU"},
    {"name": "Jane", "age": 14, "school": "SIT"},
    {"name": "Jane", "age": 16, "school": "SIT"},
    {"name": "John", "age": 13, "school": "NUS"},
]
r = {}
for x in l:
    id = f"{x['name']}-{x['school']}"
    if id in r:
        for k,v in x.items():
            if k not in ["name", "school"]:
                if k in r[id]:
                    if isinstance(r[id][k], list):
                        r[id][k].append(v)
                    else:
                        r[id][k] = [r[id][k], v]
                else:
                    r[id][k] = v
    else:
        r[id] = x

result = [x for x in r.values()]
```